Run parallel function on Apple GPU/metal in Python
I have a rather simple function that runs quite fast in parallel using Numba, and I would like to know if I can run it on my Apple M3 Max GPU. However I have never worked on GPU code before (coming from Macs), so I am a little lost..
I have included a small use case:
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

N = 15      # size of the a and b
K = 127     # size of the result
L = 943     # size of the operator

a = np.random.standard_normal(size=N)
b = np.random.standard_normal(size=N)

operator = np.zeros(shape=(L, 4), dtype=np.int64)
operator[:, 0] = np.random.randint(size=L, low=0, high=N)
operator[:, 1] = np.random.randint(size=L, low=0, high=N)
operator[:, 2] = np.random.randint(size=L, low=0, high=K)
operator[:, 3] = np.random.randint(size=L, low=1, high=10)

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def shuffle_mul(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, operator: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    res = np.zeros(shape=K, dtype=a.dtype)
    for n in nb.prange(len(operator)):
        i, j, k, count = operator[n]
        res[k] += count * a[i] * b[j]
    return res

shuffle_mul(a, b, operator=operator)  # warm-up
%timeit shuffle_mul(a, b, operator=operator)  # 173 µs ± 41.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

Question 1: Is it even theoretically possible/interesting to run such a function on GPU? The fact that multiple instances might read a and b or add to res at the same time is a problem?
Question 2: What would be the best approach? Also, what library should I use? metalcompute, jax, PyTorch, ... ?
Thanks a lot!

parallel is designed to spawn processes on multiple CPU cores. You can't use it as-is on GPU. GPUs work a bit differently - you would format res[k] += count * a[i] * b[j] as your kernel function and parallelize that on GPU. You can look into Numba Cuda and torch vmap

multiple threads already read a and b and add to res at the same time meaning you have race conditions and your code doesn't give the same result as a sequential one. You can see this by changing operator[:, 2] = np.random.randint(size=L, low=0, high=K) to operator[:, 2] = np.random.randint(size=L, low=0, high=1) for example and also compiling shuffle_mul with parallel=False - the results are significantly different

The code with parallel=False is also significantly faster for this example 1.72us vs 139us for me - is this a representative example or are the real arrays larger to make the parallelism worth it?

Significantly larger: at least of the order of N= 100, K= 10,000 and L= 1,000,000.

Also, operator is totally deterministic in the true case, I just didn't want to include too many lines. And I think low=0, high=1 can only give 0s.

Ok with N=100, K=10_000 and L=1_000_000 it is still 1.6x faster to run the code in series vs in parallel for me on an M1 Pro 1.3ms v 2.2ms. The problem is not whether operator is deterministic, it is caused by repeated values of k, so using a low range in the rng highlights the problem as there are many repeated indices. A JAX function with jax-metal is timing at 14.8ms for me.

A fairly new library ml-explore developed for Apple Silicon can do this. In this case it would be:
res = mx.zeros(shape=K)
res.at[k].add(count * a[i] * b[j])

It's made be (almost) a drop-in replacement to NumPy or PyTorch and it is fast. The drawback is that it doesn't support float64 so precision is not as good.
